# C# scripting (python)

Tags: c#, python, scripting

Does a way to interoperate in `C#` and `Python` exist?

*I know and have used `IronPython` (obviously, it became really sweet with the `dynamic` keyword), and it allows to interpret `Python` scripts inside a `C#` application.*

But I want this `Python` script to access C# classes and methods. I know, for example, this can be implemented using `boost::python` and `C++`, but how should I (if it's **possible**) do it with `C#`?

Thanks.

Comment: IronPython *should* be able to use C# classes as they're all .NET

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use a C# dll in IronPython](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200182/how-to-use-a-c-dll-in-ironpython)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well you *could* compile your C# code to a DLL using `csc` and [use ctypes to access the DLL from your script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252417/how-can-i-use-a-dll-from-python) but if you *can* use IronPython, then that's the route I'd go with.

Using C# modules from IronPython is as simple as a call to `clr.AddReference`. For example, here's a script to make your computer talk to you (taken from the [IronPython Cookbook](http://www.ironpython.info/index.php/Speech_Synthesis))

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('System.Speech')
from System.Speech.Synthesis import SpeechSynthesizer

spk = SpeechSynthesizer()
spk.Speak('Hello world!')
```