# Importing dlls work from python interpreter but not from script file

Tags: python, python-2.7, clr, cpython

I am suing CPython 2.7 and have installed Python for NET clr package. I DO NOT want to use Iron Python.

When I run the python from MING32 command line it works:

```
PC@User /c/Users
$ python
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jun 30 2014, 16:03:49) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import clr
>>> clr.AddReference(r"C:\Users\MasterEmulator")
<System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly object at 0x02368F30>
```

Howeever if I executed th same code from python script it fails:

```
PC@User /c/Users
$ cat s.py
import clr
clr.AddReference(r"C:\Users\MasterEmulator")


PC@User /c/Users
$ python s.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "s.py", line 2, in <module>
    clr.AddReference(r"C:\Users\MasterEmulator")
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Unable to find assembly 'C:\Users\MasterEmulator'.
   at Python.Runtime.CLRModule.AddReference(String name)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: This script however works. Seems so problem with absolute paths...

```
import clr
clr.AddReference(r"../Users/MasterEmulator")
```

Answer (score 1):

[How to use a C# dll in IronPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200182/how-to-use-a-c-sharp-dll-in-ironpython)

sys.path.append(r"C:\Folder\Subfolder")  # path of dll

clr.AddReference ("Ipytest.dll") # the dll