# Convert python modules into DLL file

Tags: c#, python, wpf, numpy, dll

I am building a GUI using WPF on .NET Framework.I want to run python script (which uses modules like numpy, scipy ,etc) using C#.
Now, I have two options.

1. Process `p = new Process();` *//by passing necessary parameters like "python.exe" and "filename.py"*
2. Using IronPython

Using *Method#1* is pretty much simpler but If I distribute this Application,then my End-User must have those python modules in the path specified by me in my Application.
Using *Method#2* I am facing problems with those python modules because they don't come with IronPython and I need DLL files of those modules.
So is there any way to Convert Python Modules like numpy, scipy into DLL files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use clr.CompileModules to turn the python files into dll ones. You can add all the files into a single dll by doing something like this:

```
from System import IO
from System.IO.Path import Combine

def walk(folder):
  for file in IO.Directory.GetFiles(folder):
    yield file
  for folder in IO.Directory.GetDirectories(folder):
    for file in walk(folder): yield file

folder = IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(__file__)
all_files = list(walk(Combine(folder, 'moduleName')))

import clr
clr.CompileModules(Combine(folder, "myDll.dll"), *all_files)
```

You can then add a reference to your dll by doing something like this:

```
import clr
import sys

sys.path.append(r"C:\Path\To\Dll")
clr.AddReference("myDll.dll")
```

I don't however know how to access the functions inside that dll. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200182/how-to-use-a-c-sharp-dll-in-ironpython), you can import it by doing `import moduleName`. This does not work for me though.

Sources: [[add files to single dll]](http://devhawk.net/blog/2009/8/10/compiling-python-packages-into-assemblies) [[reference dll]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200182/how-to-use-a-c-sharp-dll-in-ironpython)