# Can IronPython call .net dll directly?

Tags: c#, python, .net, ironpython

I am new to .net programming. I heard all .net supported languages can call .net dll even written by another .net supported languages. My question is that: Can IronPython call .net dll written by c# directly or easily under its command interpretation window?

Comment: you can also use pythonnet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to call any managed dll.
An example of how you would do that is detailed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/14210917/413672